# Replacing implementation of a trait during tests in PlayFramework?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice, playframework-2.6

I have a trait `Config` which contains a bunch of configuration values.

I have a default impl of this trait, `DefaultConfig` , which contains the production values of these fields. I use `@ImplementedBy( classOf[DefaultConfig] )` on `Config`, and in my controllers, it gets injected as:

`class SignupController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, config: Config)`

This all works so far - but I'd like to have another implementation of `Config`, called `TestConfig`, which contains credentials to a test database, etc. I'd like to have `TestConfig` rather than `DefaultConfig` be injected during tests.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? My tests extend from `PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with Injecting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the test application you can override the injected class:

```
override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .overrides(bind[Config].to[TestConfig])
      .build
```

Comment: Should one override `GuiceFakeApplicationFactory::fakeApplication` with that, or where should this go?

Comment: yeah I forgot the override, just updated the answer, you can just put this at the beggining of your test file

Comment: I also had forgotten the build call

Comment: The way I did this is to have a base test class which contains this exact line ^ and all tests inherit from that. Thank you!